# Error during UWP app launch in Windows 10 mobile

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile, cortana

I have an UWP app with a lot of errors in dev center console during launch such as this: 
**em_watchdog_timeout_deada444_514cabuxamapache.391043fc20bb3_fa4730peekfge!lockscreenimages.exe_timeout_expired:_event_type_=_targetstatechanged,_timeout_modifier_type_=_none,_server_task_currentstate_=_navigatingto,*targetstate*=_active.**
I suspect it's due to Cortana or Analitycs activation in "App.cs":

```
private async Task SetupVoiceCommands()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile vcdStorageFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Commands.xml");
            await VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync(vcdStorageFile);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Installing Voice Commands Failed: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

private void InitAnalyticsTracker()
    {
        GoogleAnalyticsTracker = AnalyticsManager.Current.CreateTracker("UA-XXXXXXXX");
        AnalyticsManager.Current.ReportUncaughtExceptions = true;
        AnalyticsManager.Current.AutoAppLifetimeMonitoring = true;
        AnalyticsManager.Current.IsDebug = false;
    }
```

This code is executed in:

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
        {
            await SetupVoiceCommands();

            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                InitAnalyticsTracker();

                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Shell), e.Arguments);
            }
            else
            {
                var page = rootFrame.Content as Shell;
                page?.OnLaunchedEvent(e.Arguments);
            }

            Window.Current.Activate();

            CustomizeStatusBar();
        }
    }
```

A lot of users say the app does not even start...
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call `await SetupVoiceCommands();` blocks the rest of the code in the `OnLaunched` method: until the execution of `SetupVoiceCommands()` is finished the main page of the app won't be displayed (which is supposed to happen within a short period of time after the app launch, otherwise the system will shut down your app as not responding).

Consider moving the `await SetupVoiceCommands();` closer to the end of the `OnLaunched` method, e.g. after `CustomizeStatusBar();`.

To get a better understanding of how it affects the flow of execution and the launch time of the app, you could replace the call `await SetupVoiceCommands();` with `await Task.Delay(5000);` to imitate the delay and then try moving it around the `OnLaunched` method as suggested.

Comment: I will try it today and send you a feedback, thanks for your answer!!

Comment: @Cabuxa.Mapache Good luck!

Comment: @Cabuxa.Mapache Happy to help.

Comment: @a-milto By the way, that helped me to fix the issue in Wal 9000 app, if you want to try ;)